# Verify the axioms of a weird category

Tags: category-theory

This exercise asks me to verify the axiom of a really weirdly defined category:

> Define a category $\mathcal{C}$ as follows:
>
> $(1)$ There is only one object $*$;
>
> $(2)$ The set of morphism $Mor(*,*)$ consists of the algebraic terms $t:=x_{0}|f(t)|g(t,t)$, where $x_{0}$ is a given variable and $f, g$ are two given function symbols;
>
> $(3)$ The composition law is a substitution recursively defined as $t(t')$, where $t'$ replace $x_{0}$ in $t$.

The exercise then asks me to check the axioms and to describe the set of all isomorphism $Iso(*,*)$.

Well the first axiom is trivial true since there is only object.

Then we just need to check that the existence of two-sided identity element in $Mor(*,*)$ and  check the associativity of the composition.

Since the construction of composition is really weird, I tried to compute one composition and to see what is going on. **However,** after the computation, I had no idea if this composition is even well-defined

---

For $t_{1}, t_{2}\in Mor(*,*)$, by definition we have $$t_{1}:=x_{0}|f(t_{1})|g(t_{1}, t_{1})\ \text{and}\ t_{2}:=x_{0}|f(t_{2})|g(t_{2}, t_{2}),$$ so that by the construction of the law of composition, we have
\begin{align*}
t_{2}\circ t_{1}:=t_{2}(t_{1})&=t_{1}|f(t_{2})|g(t_{2}, t_{2})\\
&=x_{0}|f(t_{1})|g(t_{1}, t_{1})|f(t_{2})|g(t_{2}, t_{2})\\
&=x_{0}|f(t_{2})f(t_{1})|g(t_{2}, t_{2})g(t_{1}, t_{1}).
\end{align*}

---

However, I still need to show $|f(t_{2})f(t_{1})|=|f(t_{2}\circ t_{1})|$ and $g(t_{2}, t_{2})g(t_{1}, t_{1})=g(t_{2}\circ t_{1}, t_{2}\circ t_{1})$, right? Because if the composition is well-defined, we should have $$t_{2}\circ t_{1}=x_{0}|f(t_{2}\circ t_{1})|g(t_{2}\circ t_{1}, t_{2}\circ t_{1})\in Mor(*,*),$$ right?

But I don't see any way to show this. Also, what is the identity element in this case? Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a reference to something defining an "algebraic term" and the notation you're using? I've never heard of these things.

Comment: @jgon I don't know what it exactly means either... I just found this exercise and tried to do it. The notation is really weird... I think by the words "algebraic term", it means that the definition is algebraic. Specifically, the definition can be given using only equations between terms with free variables.

Comment: @jgon a free variable, by Wikipedia, is a symbol that specifies places in the expression where substitution may take place

Comment: It seems to me that the definition $t:=x_{0}|f(t)|g(t,t)$ is a formal grammar expressed in a simplified form of [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form). That is, the morphisms are formal expressions freely generated by a variable $x_0$ or applying a unary function $f(t)$ or a binary function $g(t,t)$. The composition is just composition of formal expressions regarded as functions of a single variable.

Comment: @Somos I took a deep look in the link you provided, and then I believe you are correct.. that is why this exercise is this weird.. Would you mind posing an answer? I believe only using your comments will be perfect! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is well-known, a category with just one
object is actually a monoid, no more or less. I 
think that the formal definition of morphism as
$\, t:=x_{0}|f(t)|g(t,t) \,$
seems like a simplified form of [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) definition of a simple grammar. What it essentially states is that the language
consists of a single variable denoted by $\,x_0,\,$ and one (or more) unary functions denoted by $\,f\,$ and one (or more)
binary functions denoted by $\,g.\,$
An example of such a language expressions is $\,g(x_0,f(x_0))\,$
which denotes the function defined by 
$\, x_0 \mapsto g(x_0,f(x_0)).\,$
The composition law of the category (monoid)
is just composition of the functions which
the expressions denote, and of course, function
composition is always associative.